# Reading and writing files using haskell after encrypting and decrypting them

Tags: haskell, encryption, file-io

I recently started to work on DES algorithm using haskell. I made two functions `des` and `indes` which, similar to DES, takes 16 hexadecimal of input and a 16 hexadecimal of key and then encrypt and decrypt them respectively. I wrote a function to take input from a file as arguments and the apply the required process accordingly. My encryption process is working good but the decryption process is showing the error `Prelude.!!: index too large` I gave multilines input in the function `dens` and it works. But, whenever I try to write it in the file, I give the same error. I am attaching only the significant code as I assume the function `des` and `indes` works fine.

```
denc :: String->String->String
denc [] _ = []
denc xs sx = if ((length xs)>=16) then (des (take 16 xs) sx ++ denc (drop 16 xs) sx) else (des (take 16 (xs ++ (repeat '0'))) sx)

dens :: String->[Char]->[Char]
dens [] _ = []
dens xs sx = (indes (take 16 xs) sx) ++ (dens (drop 16 xs) sx)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x:y:z:_ <- getArgs
    handle <- openFile y ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle 
    if (z=="encrypt") then (do
            hanle <- openFile "cipher.txt" WriteMode
            let some = unlines $ unhex (denc (hex contents) (hex x))
            hPutStrLn hanle some
            hClose hanle
        ) else (do
            hanlee <- openFile "decipher.txt" WriteMode
            let some = unlines $ unhex (dens (hex contents) (hex x))
            hPutStrLn hanlee some
            hClose hanlee
                )
hClose handle
```

Comment: The error message says that you're calling the `(!!)` operator with an invalid index. And yet, the code you posted doesn't use this operator anywhere. I'm going to say the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I get that. But in that case ,why is my function giving me the correct result when I am providing the input manually which is more than 16 hexadecimal in size?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, we can only speculate. Maybe try looking for all the places that `(!!)` is used?

Comment: I understand completely. I will look at my code again. However, as it is a 190 line code, I decided not to upload my full code. Thanks for your valuable response.

Comment: If the broken code is too large, the helpful response is, "I will find a shorter program with the same problem!", not, "I will post only part of my program!".

Comment: I tried to find that. But individually, my different parts of code show no error. As I said, manual input gives no error. That is why I thought that the revelant part of the code would be this and hence the question

Answer (score 1):

Enabling profiling and using the RTS -xc option will display a stack trace when an exception occurs, and this might help locate the problem:

```
ghc program.hs -prof -fprof-auto
program ...args... +RTS -xc
```